# Problem while looping through all AppointmentItems of a Calendar

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar, appointment, comobject

i need to get all AppointmentItems from a Calendar, but after a few Items i got an exception with an error thats says that the maximum of opened items is limited. I don´t loop them through an foreach-loop so there should be no problem with the reference. I instantly "convert" these Items into my Type of Item so that i can Release the Objects. I also set the reference of the object to null after i released the Object AND i tried to call the Garbage Collector but the Error still occurs.

```
Items items = application.Session.GetFolderFromID(MainCalendar).Items;
for(Int32 i = 1; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    AppointmentItem appointmentItem = items[i] as AppointmentItem;
    TempOutlookAppointment tempApp = new TempOutlookAppointment();
    tempApp.FillFromAppointmentItem(appointmentItem);
    appointmentItem.Close(OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appointmentItem);
    appointmentItem = null;
    GC.Collect();
    // Adding tempApp to a List
}



// FillFromAppointmentItem
public void FillFromAppointmentItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem appointmentItem)
{
        AllDayEvent = appointmentItem.AllDayEvent;
        Body = appointmentItem.Body;
        End = appointmentItem.End;
        Location = appointmentItem.Location;
        OutlookLinkID = appointmentItem.UserProperties.Find("LINKID") != null
            ? Guid.Parse(appointmentItem.UserProperties.Find("LINKID").Value.ToString())
            : Guid.Empty;
        Start = appointmentItem.Start;
        if (appointmentItem.IsRecurring)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.RecurrencePattern pattern = appointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern();
            TerminSerie serie = new TerminSerie()
            {
                MaxOccurences = pattern.Occurrences,
                PatternDayOfMonth = pattern.DayOfMonth,
                PatternFrequency = pattern.RecurrenceType == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlRecurrenceType.olRecursDaily ? PatternFrequency.Daily : pattern.RecurrenceType == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlRecurrenceType.olRecursMonthly ? PatternFrequency.Monthly : pattern.RecurrenceType == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlRecurrenceType.olRecursWeekly ? PatternFrequency.Weekly : PatternFrequency.Yearly,
                PatternInterval = pattern.RecurrenceType == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlRecurrenceType.olRecursMonthly ? pattern.Interval / 12 : pattern.Interval,
                PatternMonthOfYear = pattern.MonthOfYear,
                RangeEndDate = pattern.PatternEndDate,
                RangeLimit = pattern.NoEndDate ? RangeLimit.NoLimit : pattern.Occurrences > 0 ? RangeLimit.ByOccurences : RangeLimit.ByDate,
                RangeStartDate = pattern.PatternStartDate
            };
            Int32 i = pattern.DayOfWeekMask.GetHashCode();
            List<System.DayOfWeek> days = new List<System.DayOfWeek>();
            if (i >= 64)
            {
                days.Add(System.DayOfWeek.Saturday);
                i -= 64;
            }
            if (i >= 32)
            {
                days.Add(System.DayOfWeek.Friday);
                i -= 32;
            }
            if (i >= 16)
            {
                days.Add(System.DayOfWeek.Thursday);
                i -= 16;
            }
            if (i >= 8)
            {
                days.Add(System.DayOfWeek.Wednesday);
                i -= 8;
            }
            if (i >= 4)
            {
                days.Add(System.DayOfWeek.Tuesday);
                i -= 4;
            }
            if (i >= 2)
            {
                days.Add(System.DayOfWeek.Monday);
                i -= 2;
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                days.Add(System.DayOfWeek.Sunday);
            }
            serie.PatternDaysOfWeek = days;
        }
        Subject = appointmentItem.Subject;
    }
```

I hope you can help my with my Problem.

Comment: Possibly try [ReleaseComObject](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ccd37f91-0196-4581-86bd-54fe73d8c86b/c-outlook-marshalreleasecomobject?forum=vsto)

Comment: I tried. Also in the code i posted - for-loop => "Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appointmentItem);"

Comment: looks like it was the release object, can you mark yours as the answer if this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5 Days I just don't understood why this isn't working, now I got randomly a solution.

For those who have the same Problem: I just had to change this line:

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appointmentItem);
```

to this one:

```
while(Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appointmentItem) > 0)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appointmentItem);
```

I don't now why, but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You still have an implicit variable. Change the following

```
AppointmentItem appointmentItem = items[i] as AppointmentItem;
...
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appointmentItem);
```

to

```
object item = items[i];
AppointmentItem appointmentItem = item as AppointmentItem;
...
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appointmentItem);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
```

Comment: In my Solution when i release "appointmentItem" i dont release an AppointmentItem object, i release the object you want me to create an release additionally, because the appointmentItem i create ist a reference to the object

Comment: No, think what compiler does on that line in your code  - it retrieves an object from items[i], stores it in an implicit variable, than casts it to AppointmentItem and stores it in your explicit variable. You released the latter, but not the former.

Comment: The latter is a reference to the former. So when i release the latter i also release the former. Otherwise my code wouldn't work.. and.. i't works

Comment: Both variables refer to the same object, but each, of course, maintains its own reference count. Both need to  be released separately by calling ReleaseComObject once. Calling ReleaseComObject in a loop is a horrible idea. DO NOT DO THAT. It is a bandaid - you need to fix the actual problem: you have a reference count leak.